# Is there a quick way to get groups together?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there some *World of Warcraft* meeting stone/Warlock summon analog in *The Old Republic* to quickly assemble groups and fetch that last straggler that takes 5 minutes to walk across the station?

There's Quick Travel, but that doesn't always get you close (especially when trying to do Heroic 4 quests in the middle of a forest), plus some people might have it on cooldown.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a way to do that yet. However, there are a few things you can do to ensure your party doesn't spend all night waiting on the laggard:

1. **Kick him from the party** - It's by far the easiest solution, although the one that helps you least at the time. Bur for those people that can never seem to make to the meet up point on anything resembling time, it is the final solution.
2. **Use your fleet pass** - That eighteen hour cooldown is a bit of a b*tch, but it also means most people aren't in the habit of using it, so you can use it to meet at the fleet and roll out together, group already formed. you can even take the same ship as long as you let every one touch the door before the owner.
3. **Speeder bikes for the win** - The speeder bike network should get you close to any mission you might be running.  Assuming that you have the network discovered in the first place that is... so always grab those first off.

All that said, even at low level, I haven't found any place that I couldn't get to in less than ten to fifteen minutes using a combination of the above tactics.  It also helps to schedule stuff for specific times so that people can assemble without the originator standing around for all that time.  If you do end up waiting, hey, at least you got some crafting time or something.

Comment: One method I've seen used on my server was for people to go to the entrance of whatever mission/instance you were planning to do, then simply recruit whoever was standing around. One guy even asked me to go there before he'd invite me, which does make sense: Just grab the first 3 players that get there and whoever runs late can just form another group when they get there (if there's sufficient interest).

Comment: Quick Travel and taxis are useful too.